# Windows 8 html/js: Alternative to <img> / removing the 'dragging' functionality?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is there an alternative or a more preferred way of displaying images in Win 8 HTML/JS/CSS programming? Is the  tag the standard way to display image? If I test my app with a mouse I can 'drag' an image around inside the app which is of course useless - at least as far as my app's concerned. This feature is usually used to save images by dragging images into an explorer window - but this doesn't even work so the feature is basically useless for Win8.
Is there a way to turn it off?

The only other way that wouldn't drag around is probably to use divs with image background.

Comment: You've already answered your own question. By the way is that Windows 8 specific?

Comment: Would setting ondragstart="return false" fix it?

Comment: I've answered my own question in terms of web programming is concerned. I wasn't sure if there was anything the Win8 API that would help

Comment: nope, `ondragstart="return false"` didn't do anything

Comment: How about adding `draggable="false"` attribute?

Comment: `draggable="false"` also does nothing

Comment: Well, that's weird; `draggable=false` actually fixed the dragging of images in browsers AND IE10 (finally) supports it, so I'm a bit lost for explanations here. BTW, one _can_ drag background images; I just did it with SO logo. )

Comment: Well then maybe I'm doing it wrong? 

`<img draggable="false" src="/images/protoss.png" />`

Can you usually drag background images around in browsers? Or does it just do it in Win8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is an artifact of the browser supporting the dragging of images.  Open up IE on any machine and you can drag image elements around like you do in a metro js app.  To get around this problem you could use a div with a background image:

HTML:

```
<div class="art" ></div>
```

CSS:

```
.art {
    background-image: url(../images/art.png);
    height:128px;
    width:128px;
}
```